# 'Learn projects the hard way': logfind project

Tags: python, beginner, regex, file

I'm a new programmer, who has just finished his first small project.

It's a sort of basic imitation of the `grep` command from Linux. I'm learning from *projects the hard way*.  Here is the [description](http://projectsthehardway.com/2015/06/16/project-1-logfind-2/) of the project:

> The first project that we’ll try is called logfind. It’s nothing more than a simple version of grep so you can learn a few simple basic things in Python:
>
> 1. Opening files based on regular expressions in a file.
> 2. Scanning those files for strings from command line arguments.
> 3. Create a complete installable Python project.

When I run the script, the first thing it will look for is`logfind.txt` file on the user's computer, then it will scan this file according to a regular expression to search for filenames of the `example.extension` type. The files specified in the `logfind.txt` file will be searched for the strings that the user has specified on the command line.

I have a few questions about my program:

- Could someone critique my code on style and readability?
- Could you also check the overall design of the code and evaluate it?
- Are there functions that's syntax can be shortened?

Source code:

```
# logfind.py
# Project explanation: http://projectsthehardway.com/
# A basic implementation of the linux grep command. The program will search for the given strings in files that are listed in a logfind.txt file. 
# By default the program will search for all the given strings in a file. If -o option is enabled, the program will return the file if one of the strings is present. 
# The results will be written to results.txt located in the current working directory.

import argparse
import os
import re

def cl_handler():
    """
    Handles the command line input, with strings as the words to search for in files, and -o as optional argument
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="find strings inside files")
    parser.add_argument("strings", nargs = "*", help="The files will be searched according to this words")
    parser.add_argument("-o", action="store_true", help="This option resets the string1 AND string2 and string3 logic to a string1 OR string2 OR string3 search logic")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.strings, args.o


def scan_logfind(logfind_dir):
    """
    Opens the logfind file and scans it for filenames according to a regular expression (filename.extension). 
    Returns a list with the filenames
    """
    files = []
    with open(logfind_dir, "r") as logfind:
        regex = re.compile(r"^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$")  
        for word in logfind.read().split():            
            file = regex.match(word)
            if file:
                files.append(word)
    return files


def scan_directory(file):
    """
    Scans the computer for a specified file, starting with the home directory. 
    Returns the absolute directory of the file
    """
    home = os.path.expanduser("~")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home):
        for f in files:
            if f == file:        
               file_directory = os.path.join(root, f)
               return file_directory


def search_strings(file_dir, strings, or_option=False):
    """
    Searches the file for the specified files. Returns boolean true if all strings are found in the file
    If the or_option is enabled the function will return boolean true if one string is found in the file.
    """
    with open(file_dir, "r") as logfile:
        logfile = logfile.read().lower()
        results = []
        for string in strings:
            if string in logfile:
                results.append("True")
            else:
                results.append("False")

    if or_option:
        for result in results:
            if result == "True":
                return True
        return False
    else:
        for result in results:
            if result == "False":
                return False
        return True


def main():
    """ 
    main 
    """
    results = open("results.txt", "w")
    strings, or_option = cl_handler()                 
    logfind = scan_directory("logfind.txt")          

    logfiles = scan_logfind(logfind)
    logfiles_dir = []        
    for logfile in logfiles:
        logfiles_dir.append(scan_directory(logfile))
    for logfile_dir in logfiles_dir:
            if search_strings(logfile_dir, strings, or_option):
                results.write("{}\n".format(logfile_dir))
    print("Search complete. Results written to results.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generators**

Sometimes you make a list a piece at a time, to write a generator function you just `yield` the result each iteration and not build a list, the pattern:

```
result = []
for i in a_thing:
    result.append(do_thing(i))
return result
```

Must be avoided as it wastes memory and is boilerplate.

More concretely, you have:

```
def scan_logfind(logfind_dir):
    """
    Opens the logfind file and scans it for filenames according to a regular expression (filename.extension). 
    Returns a list with the filenames
    """
    files = [] # <- 1
    with open(logfind_dir, "r") as logfind:
        regex = re.compile(r"^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$")  
        for word in logfind.read().split():            
            file = regex.match(word)
            if file:
                files.append(word) # <- 2
    return files # <- 3
```

You should write:

```
def scan_logfind(logfind_dir):
    """
    Opens the logfind file and scans it for filenames according to a regular expression (filename.extension). 
    Returns a generator with the filenames
    """
    ## Deleted -- files = [] # <- 1
    with open(logfind_dir, "r") as logfind:
        regex = re.compile(r"^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$")  
        for word in logfind.read().split():            
            file = regex.match(word)
            if file:
                yield word # Gives this element out of the function.
    ## Deleted -- return files # <- 3
```

**Ternary when sensible**

Ternaries should not be overused, but can be a valuable tool to reduce code-bloat, see:

```
        if string in logfile:
            results.append("True")
        else:
            results.append("False")
```

The action `append` is the same, only the value changes, a perfect job for ternaries:

```
results.append("True" if string in logfile else "False")
```

But the whole top part of the function `search_strings` should be a generator expression as noted above.

**Temporary overuse**

You really like temporary variables, I would make less use of them, especially if they got confusing names:

```
file = regex.match(word) # This is not a filename nor a filecontent
```

Just write:

```
if regex.match(word):
    yield word
```

Another example:

```
       file_directory = os.path.join(root, f)
       return file_directory
```

This follows the:

```
result = computation(thing)
return result
```

Anti-pattern, just write:

```
return os.path.join(root, f)
```

---

**A case analysis: `search_strings`**

`search_strings` was the worst of your functions considering all the wheels that you reinvented there. Python has a ton of built-ins, please use them.

A first refactor was just:

- Reducing nesting by closing the file early.
- Using generator expressions.
- Using the built-ins `all` and `any`

```
def search_strings(file_dir, strings, or_option=False):
    """
    Searches the file for the specified files. Returns boolean true if all strings are found in the file
    If the or_option is enabled the function will return boolean true if one string is found in the file.
    """
    with open(file_dir, "r") as f:
        logfile = f.read().lower()

    results = ("True" if string in logfile else "False" for string in strings)

    if or_option:
        return any(result == "True" for result in results)
    else:
        return all(result == "True" for result in results)
```

After:

- Realizing you are using `"True"` instead of `True` for misterious reasons.
- Using a ternary for more FP.

```
def search_strings(file_dir, strings, or_option=False):
    """
    Searches the file for the specified files. Returns boolean true if all strings are found in the file
    If the or_option is enabled the function will return boolean true if one string is found in the file.
    """
    with open(file_dir, "r") as f:
        logfile = f.read().lower()

    any_or_all = (any if or_option else all)
    return any_or_all(string in logfile for string in strings)
```

A FP purist would avoid all temporary variables and write it like:

```
def search_strings(file_dir, strings, or_option=False):
    """
    Searches the file for the specified files. Returns boolean true if all strings are found in the file
    If the or_option is enabled the function will return boolean true if one string is found in the file.
    """
    with open(file_dir, "r") as f:
        return (any if or_option else all)(string in f.read().lower() for string in strings)
```

The second and third versions are more or less readable to different people, choosing between them is subjective, but surely any of them is better than your version (3-7 lines vs 20 of yours and are simpler then it).

Answer (score 2):

You should parse command line inputs when you know you script is invoked from the command line. This allows you to more easily test your `main` function in the interactive interpreter and avoid importing `argparse` when it’s not needed. I’d rather write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    # Handles the command line input, with strings as the words to search for in files, and -o as optional argument
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="find strings inside files")
    parser.add_argument("strings", nargs = "*", help="The files will be searched according to this words")
    parser.add_argument("-o", action="store_true", help="This option resets the string1 AND string2 and string3 logic to a string1 OR string2 OR string3 search logic")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.strings, args.o)
```

and modify `main` accordingly. But reusing your function in the same kind of context is also valid:

```
def cl_handler():
    """
    Handles the command line input, with strings as the words to search for in files, and -o as optional argument
    """
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="find strings inside files")
    parser.add_argument("strings", nargs = "*", help="The files will be searched according to this words")
    parser.add_argument("-o", action="store_true", help="This option resets the string1 AND string2 and string3 logic to a string1 OR string2 OR string3 search logic")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.strings, args.o

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*cl_handler())
```

---

Also note that

```
"""
main
"""
```

serves absolutely no purpose. It has no added value and is just noise. Either write a proper docstring or write nothing at all.

Comment: It is a convention to  group imports at the top to know what is being used in the file at a first glance. `argparse` is in the standard library, so there is no harm in importing it every time.

Comment: @Caridorc I’m aware of that convention and usually follow it, but for the case of `argparse` I tend to only include it in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` part. I mean, it has absolutely no use otherwise and serves only to bootstrap calls in this portion of the code, so why bother when it’s not needed? I can't find anything to reinforce that claim, though, so I might want to reconsider it. Note, however, that the point of the answer was also (mainly?) to reconsider the coupling between `main` and `argparse` and remove the need of the latter when executing the former.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module is a nice discussion in the topic, anyhow in this case `import argparse` may live anywhere, it is minor.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your first project, then you are off to a good start!  I see many commendable qualities:

- Functionality is logically organized into functions, with no free-floating code outside of functions
- Following the `if __name__ == "__main__"` convention
- Docstrings ([Please keep the line length under 72, though!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length))
- Using `argparse` instead of reinventing the wheel

### Spec compliance

Why are you recursively scanning my entire home directory for files named `logfind.txt`?  Some people's home directory can be huge.  The project description just says *I specify what files are important in a `~/.logfind` file, using regular expressions.*

Why do you write your results to `results.txt`?  That's unexpected — conventionally, results would just be printed to `sys.stdout`.  You could be overwriting my valuable data.  If you do write to `results.txt`, at least open it with the `x` flag to ensure that you don't overwrite anything.  Also note that you neglected to use a `with` block when opening `results.txt` as you did in `scan_logfind()`.

### `search_strings()`

Why is the first parameter named `file_dir`?  It's supposed to be a text file, not a directory.

Using special strings `"True"` and `"False"` is weird.  Why not use booleans `True` and `False`?

It's bad practice to reassign `logfile = logfile.read().lower()` in a way that changes its type from a file handle to a string.

The exercise encourages you to write a fast solution.  The costliest operations in this problem are ones involving disk I/O.  Specifically, you should try to **avoid reading the entire file at once** with `logfile.read()`, because:

- It scales poorly if `logfile` is large.
- You may be able to avoid reading the rest of the file if the keywords occur early in the file.

I'd rewrite `search_strings()` like this:

```
def file_contains_strings(file_path, strings, conjunction=all):
    """Checks whether the file contains the specified strings.

    The conjunction should be either the builtin function all()
    (the default) or any().
    """
    search = { text.lower(): False for text in strings }
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.lower()
            for text, found in search.items():
                search[text] = found or (text in line)
            if conjunction(search.values()):
                return True
    return False
```

Instead of passing `or_option`, the caller specifies [`all` or `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), which is more self-documenting (and it also simplifies the implementation of this function).  I've renamed the function as a predicate rather than a procedure, so that the code at the call site reads better:

```
if file_contains_strings(logfile, strings, any if or_option else all):
    …
```

Note that lowercasing the text is technically [not the right way to do case-insensitive search](//stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/1157100).